# the response of $.ajax POST includes an sql INSERT that I made beforeand I don't know why

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery code my webpage uses to call a php file that inserts a row in a mysql BD. The problem is I should get data from server in JSON but I receive the data I expect but I recive the sql instruction sent in the php file to the mysql DB too. Why?

jquery code:

```
$("#botoPreReserva").click(function(){
            var dataArribada=$("#dataArribada").val();
            var dataSortida=$("#dataSortida").val();
            var firstname=$("#firstname").val();
            var lastname=$("#lastname").val();
            var email=$("#email").val();
            var message=$("#message").val();
            var req=$.ajax({
              method:"POST",
              url:"comprovardates.php",
              data:{arribada:dataArribada,
                    sortida:dataSortida,
                    firstname:firstname,
                    lastname:lastname,
                    email:email,
                    message:message},
              dataType:"json"


            });

           req.done(function(result){

                if(result.error != "0"){
                    $("#resultatPreReserva").text(result.errorTexte);
                }
                else{
                  $("#resultatPreReserva").text(" ");
                  //posar el calendari a l'inici de la preReserva
                  $.post("nomMes.php", {mesN:result.mesPre },
                    function(result2){
                    $("#mes").text(result2);
                  });
                  $("#any").text(result.anyPre);
                  $("#taulaCalendari").load("calendari.php",{actualmonth:result.mesPre, actualyear:result.anyPre});

                  alert(result.result);
                }

            });
            req.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
              alert(textStatus);


            });
```

and this is a comprovardades.php simplified:

```
$calendari= new Calendar(SERVERNAME,DBNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD);

//conectam a la base de dades
$calendari->connect();

// onsultam reserves d'agost del 2016
$min= new DateTime("2016-11-01");$max= new DateTime("2016-11-31"); $tipus="preReserva"; 
$event = new Event(); $event->setEntrada($min); $event->setSortida($max); $event->setTipus($tipus);

$eventList=$calendari->insertEvent($event);

echo   json_encode(array("error"=>"0","errorTexte"=>"prova","result"=>"result","mesPre"=>"01","anyPre"=>"2016"));
```

where connect():

```
    function connect(){
     try {
      $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servername;    dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      error_log("Connected successfully");
     }
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
      error_log("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
     }
    }
```

where insertEvent():

```
function insertEvent(Event $event){

$sql="INSERT INTO reserves(entrada,sortida,tipus,summary)"
        . " VALUES ('".$event->getEntrada()->format('Y-m-d')."','".$event->getSortida()->format('Y-m-d')."','".$event->getTipus()."','".$event->getSummary()."')";
echo $sql;
try{
  $this->conn->exec($sql);
  error_log("SQL:".$sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  error_log("INSERT failed " . $e->getMessage());
}

}
}
```

the response I get back to jquery something like

> INSERT INTO reserves(entrada,sortida,tipus,summary) VALUES ('2016-11-01','2016-12-01','preReserva',''
>   ){"error":"0","errorTexte":"prova","result":"result","mesPre":"01","anyPre":"201>6"}

The only way i found to solve this problem is using  ob_clean before the echo in the php file but I think it has to be a better way. I'm a noob and not sure if I skip somthing

Thanks,

Comment: answer is less than 30 chars :(

Comment: You have `echo $sql`

Comment: comment or remove echo $sql; and return some appropriate result in response.

Comment: OMG thanks for answering. I've been looking for a super complex answer and miss this echo.:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where insertEvent():

Commented out echo statement of query

```
function insertEvent(Event $event){

$sql="INSERT INTO reserves(entrada,sortida,tipus,summary)"
        . " VALUES ('".$event->getEntrada()->format('Y-m-d')."','".$event->getSortida()->format('Y-m-d')."','".$event->getTipus()."','".$event->getSummary()."')";
//echo $sql; // commented this echo 
try{
  $this->conn->exec($sql);
  error_log("SQL:".$sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  error_log("INSERT failed " . $e->getMessage());
}

}
}
```